# key mapping gone after restart

Tags: remapping

I'm trying to remap my keyboard by using the following line:

```
xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = backslash"
```

It works but it will return back to default after restarts.

How do I run this command every time I start up the computer?

I'm a extreme beginner please give me a step-by-step guide.

Thank you!

Comment: I believe there is a way to make that line of code into a small program, then add it to your Startup Aplications list. Let me look into it a little more.

Answer (score 0):

Simply, you can add your command to `/etc/rc.local` and it will be executed on system startup.

```
sudo echo "xmodmap -e \"keycode 94 = backslash\"" >> /etc/rc.local
```

Comment: it says "bash:/ etc/rc.local: Permission denied"

Comment: Well, fisrt `sudo su` then execute the command `echo "xmodmap -e \"keycode 94 = backslash\"" >> /etc/rc.local`.

Answer (score 0):

Create a file in `~/.config/autostart` with a name ending in `.desktop` (e. g. `xmodmap-backslash-94.desktop`) and fill it with this:

```
[Desktop Entry]
Exec=xmodmap -e "keycode 94 = backslash"
Terminal=false
Type=Application
X-GNOME-Autostart-enabled=true
Name=Modify keymap
Comment=Put backslash on key 94
```

The last two lines can be edited to your likes.